# Attach uploaded file to email in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I'm currently developing a simple plugin which creates a custom order status and custom email - the email is sent when the order status changed from 'Pending' to 'Processing' as the point in my plugin is so that I can send an attachment that needs to be signed by the customer, after payment has been made.

Currently, the custom order status works and the email is sent but I cannot figure out how to upload the attachment to WooCommerce / WordPress and then attach that to the email itself.

My code is relatively simple and currently consists of just two files, which can be seen below:

**woocommerce-legal-documents.php**

```
    <?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

/**
 *  Add a custom email to the list of emails WooCommerce should load
 *
 * @since 0.1
 * @param array $email_classes available email classes
 * @return array filtered available email classes
 */
function add_legal_documents_woocommerce_email( $email_classes ) {

    // include our custom email class
    require_once( 'includes/class-wc-legal-documents.php' );

    // add the email class to the list of email classes that WooCommerce loads
    $email_classes['WC_Legal_Documents_Email'] = new WC_Legal_Documents_Email();

    return $email_classes;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'add_legal_documents_woocommerce_email' );

/** 
 * Register new status
**/
function register_legal_documents_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-legal', array(
        'label'                     => 'Legal',
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Legal <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Legal <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_legal_documents_status' );

// Add to list of WC Order statuses
function add_legal_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {

    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {

        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;

        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-legal'] = 'Legal';
        }
    }

    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_legal_to_order_statuses' );

/**
 * Adds icons for any custom order statuses
**/
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'add_custom_order_status_icon' );
function add_custom_order_status_icon() {

    if( ! is_admin() ) { 
        return; 
    }

    ?> <style>
        /* Add custom status order icons */
        .column-order_status mark.legal:after {
            content: "\e004";
            font-family: WooCommerce;
            color: #ffba00;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-variant: normal;
            text-transform: none;
            line-height: 1;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            margin: 0;
            text-indent: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        /* Repeat for each different icon; tie to the correct status */

    </style> <?php
}

//enqueues our external font awesome stylesheet
function enqueue_our_required_stylesheets(){
    wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce-icons', 'includes/style.css'); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_our_required_stylesheets');
```

**includes/class-wc-legal-documents.php**

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

/**
 * A custom Expedited Order WooCommerce Email class
 *
 * @since 0.1
 * @extends \WC_Email
 */
class WC_Legal_Documents_Email extends WC_Email {


    /**
     * Set email defaults
     *
     * @since 0.1
     */
    public function __construct() {

        // set ID, this simply needs to be a unique name
        $this->id = 'wc_legal_documents';

        // this is the title in WooCommerce Email settings
        $this->title = 'Legal Documents';

        // this is the description in WooCommerce email settings
        $this->description = 'Legal Document email is sent to the customer with an attachment of the required document.';

        // these are the default heading and subject lines that can be overridden using the settings
        $this->heading = 'Legal Documents';
        $this->subject = 'Legal Documents';

        // default message to add to the email
        //$this->message = '<p>Hello,<br><br> please see attached the legal documentation in which requires your attention.</p>';

        // these define the locations of the templates that this email should use, we'll just use the new order template since this email is similar
        $this->template_html  = 'emails/customer-invoice.php';
        $this->template_plain = 'emails/plain/customer-invoice.php';

        // Trigger on new paid orders
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_notification',  array( $this, 'trigger' ) );

        // Add message
        add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', array( $this, 'add_order_email_instructions' ) );

        // Call parent constructor to load any other defaults not explicity defined here
        parent::__construct();

        // this gets the email attachments
        $this->attachment = $this->get_option( 'attachment' );

        // this gets the email message
        $this->message = $this->get_option( 'message' );
    }




    public function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {

        if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {

            //echo '<p><strong>Instructions:</strong> Full payment is due immediately upon delivery: <em>cash only, no exceptions</em>.</p>';
            echo $this->message;

        }
    }


    /**
     * Determine if the email should actually be sent and setup email merge variables
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @param int $order_id
     */
    public function trigger( $order_id ) {

        // bail if no order ID is present
        if ( ! $order_id )
            return;

        // setup order object
        $this->object = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $this->recipient = $this->object->billing_email;

        $this->object->update_status('wc-legal');

        // woohoo, send the email!
        $this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
    }


    /**
     * get_content_html function.
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_html() {
        ob_start();
        woocommerce_get_template( $this->template_html, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading()
        ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }


    /**
     * get_content_plain function.
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_plain() {
        ob_start();
        woocommerce_get_template( $this->template_plain, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading()
        ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }


    /**
     * Initialize Settings Form Fields
     *
     * @since 2.0
     */
    public function init_form_fields() {

        $this->form_fields = array(
            'enabled'    => array(
                'title'   => 'Enable/Disable',
                'type'    => 'checkbox',
                'label'   => 'Enable this email notification',
                'default' => 'yes'
            ),
            'subject'    => array(
                'title'       => 'Subject',
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => sprintf( 'This controls the email subject line. Leave blank to use the default subject: <code>%s</code>.', $this->subject ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'heading'    => array(
                'title'       => 'Email Heading',
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => sprintf( __( 'This controls the main heading contained within the email notification. Leave blank to use the default heading: <code>%s</code>.' ), $this->heading ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'message'    => array(
                'title'       => 'Message',
                'type'        => 'textarea',
                'description' => 'Add a custom message to the customer.',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'attachment'  => array(
                'title'       => 'Attachment',
                'type'        => 'file',
                'description' => 'Select the legal document to be sent as an attachment in the email.',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'email_type' => array(
                'title'       => 'Email type',
                'type'        => 'select',
                'description' => 'Choose which format of email to send.',
                'default'     => 'html',
                'class'       => 'email_type',
                'options'     => array(
                    'plain'     => __( 'Plain text', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'html'      => __( 'HTML', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'multipart' => __( 'Multipart', 'woocommerce' ),
                )
            )
        );
    }


} // end \WC_Expedited_Order_Email class
```

Also, the custom message is added to all emails that are sent out but I only need it to be added to this email but I have not been able to find a way of doing this yet - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Got 3 major issues that I can see so far. 1. you need to filter `woocommerce_email_actions` to add your custom triggers. 2. you need to override the `get_attachments()` method to include your attachment and 3. you need to write a custom WooCommerce admin setting. I was working up some code, but got stuck on #3 when I realized that your attachment never uploads or saves b/c "file" isn't a supported setting type.

Comment: Ugh, this one hooked me. I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/pull/11831) to see if WooCommerce will consider adding uploads as a setting type.